# Time slot arrangement question

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> You have $5$ students that you want to see $3$ times each over the next week. There are $15$ slots available for the students to select from. However, one of the students cannot attend the first slot. How many different ways can these students be scheduled?

Without the restriction, I believe there are $5!3!=720$ different ways. However, I am unsure how this changes with the given restriction.

Comment: How did you arrive at $5! \cdot 3!$?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I know see that it is incorrect. This question has really thrown me off. I'm very confused

Comment: If I understand it correctly, without restriction, the total number of possible ways should be (15C3) * (12C3) * (9C3) * (6C3) * (3C3)

Comment: Hint: How many ways are there to rearrange the letters in the word AAABBBCCCDDDEEE? What fraction of these start with a letter that is not A?

Comment: @Karl Are there $15!/(3!)^5$ ways to rearrange this word? If the word cannot start with A then this first slot can be filled in $12$ ways. The remaining $14$ slots can be filled in $14!$ ways. Dividing by the repeated letters, $(3!)^5$, is the answer $(12\times 14!)/(3!)^5$?

Comment: @Bell yep! What I was thinking for the first letter is: by symmetry, 1/5 of the arrangements start with A, so multiply the answer by $4/5$. The result matches yours.